# How to download lualatex engine for use in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Can anyone provide insight into how to download `lualatex` so that I can use this engine when compiling R Markdown PDFs? I have searched extensively online but have not found simple instructions for downloading. I am running under Windows 10 x64 and using R version 3.6.1.

Comment: http://www.luatex.org/download.html says “If you install the ConTeXt distribution for your platform the right binaries and some support files will end up on your computer.”

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but [`tinytex`](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) is pretty solid.